# Bintray library update not found on Android Studio project but found on IntelliJ project

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, bintray

I am working on a Kotlin library hosted on Bintray (Maven) and I use it on an Android Project(Kotlin) and in a Web Dashboard project (Kotlin with Ktor).

Both projects use Gradle for the build process and dependency management.

The problem is, when i create a new release for my library on Bintray (the library is a separate module in my android project), using `./gradlew clean publish bintrayUpload --info` and publishing the artifacts from Bintray website, I just cannot get it in my Android app via build.gradle file (`implementation "com.my:lib:version"`) but I CAN get it on my dashboard web app instantly after the release, using the same syntax.

I checked the repositories used in both projects and they are mostly the same.

I have used the library in previous versions, but i think I made the release and after a few days i updated the dependency in gradle.

My question is, why does my IntellJ projects finds the dependency but Android Studio doesn't? I mean, if there is a delay for the update to propagate on jcenter and maven servers, IntelliJ project shouldn't find it either.

Thanks!

Comment: How does it work if you build by Gradle from command line? Any errors?

Comment: What is the command for running Gradle Sync from command line? @Andrey

Comment: Use `gradlew build` to see if it builds without errors.